# Why are my particle paths offset from the particles?

Tags: particles

I'm emitting particles from a mesh off screen and they're falling down and bouncing off of the ground mesh. Everything with the particle simulation looks good, however when I set the particle display to paths, they seems to be offset from the paths the particles take. Like you can see in the image, the paths appear to collide with the ground, but it's actually offset about 0.5m from the ground.

I've tried different integration types with no luck.

[image: particle paths]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ISpKCcFnnya8jgAGJOsz8EMM0mBTYvQA/view?usp=sharing) you go, Let me know if the link isn't working.Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Chris Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using a Curve Guide for my particles. Problem was that the effector weight of "Curve Guide" (under Particle Properties -> Field Weights) was not set all the way to 1.
This fixed it for me even though I find the behaviour weird. I would expect the particles to stick less to the curve when lowering the effector weight and not offsetting it.
Edit: It is a known bug:
https://developer.blender.org/T71745